# No compiler set in kit

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I want to use `QT 5.8.0 MSVC2015 32bit kit`. But QTCreator says that it has no compiler. But as it says on Compilers tab, it has `Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler 15.0 (x86)` When I try to set this compiler manually to the kit, it just won't let me do it. I keep receiving error message

```
Error while building/deploying project EyeRec (kit: Desktop Qt 5.7.1 MSVC2015 32bit2)
When executing step "qmake"
```

I have Visual Studio 2017 installed, but still I don't know why this error appears. I'm really stuck with this.

Comment: Because your kit uses msvc2015 and you have msvc2017?

Comment: Yeah, their numbering is a constant source of a confusion. "Visual studio 2015" is also knows as VS v14. "Visual Studio 2017" is VS v15. Try to modify Visual Studio 2017 installation to include "VS 2015.3 v140 toolset". If that doesn't help, then you'll need to install VS 2015.